# Display video Django application

Tags: django, video, display, production

I'm trying to display a test video at my Django app,

this is how the .html file looked like

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" width='320' height= '240' autoplay controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="{% static 'videos/test.mp4' type='video/mp4' %}">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

{% endblock content %}
```

after setting the settings.py for defining the static root

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

also the URL patterns were adjusted:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
 #  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Now the problem is that I can display the video only using local host, and I can't display it in production using a public IP or vistual one, where I can see a video fram that can not be displayed!

I think something is missing in the settings.py for defining the URL pattern being accessed publicly during calling from a foreign router. but I can't figure it out!

I need help in amending the code!

thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure that your media file has read perimssions for others? Do `chmod 644` on it and try